# Find the supremum $\sup_{x>a} |(1+\frac{x}{n})^n-e^x| $

Tags: calculus

I want to find the supremum: $\sup_{x>a} |(1+\frac{x}{n})^n-e^x| $,where $a$ is a random number.. $e^x-(1+\frac{x}{n})^n>0$ at the interval $(a,+\infty)$..But why is it like that? Wouldn't this inequality stand at the interval $(-\infty,a)$  ?

Comment: What $a$? Your inequality is true for $a$ large enough.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla $a$ is a random number. But why does the inequality stand?

Answer (score 2):

As $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ is a polynomial,
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^x-(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=+\infty$$
and
$$\sup_{x>a}\left|(1+\frac{x}{n})^n-e^x\right|=+\infty$$
trivially.

Moreover,
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x-(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=-\infty$$
for $n$ even and
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x-(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=+\infty$$
for $n$ odd.

The behavior of this function is only interesting near zero.